# Vim load all files containing a string

Tags: linux, bash, vim

i have this code at the beginning of many of my files :

`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">`

for selecting fles i use :
`vim *`

I want to select all files and subdirectories containing this code with **vim**

Comment: Something like `grep -FlZ 'string' ./* | xargs -0 sh -c 'vim "$@" </dev/tty' sh` should work fine.

Comment: finallyt, this solution worked ```grep -FlZ '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">' **/*.php | xargs -0 sh -c 'vim "$@" </dev/tty' sh``` thank you

Comment: Read about :grep and :copen commands. This way you can navigate through the results from within vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vim $(grep -d skip -l '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">' *)
```

Will search for your string (at any position) in the files of the current directory and open those containing it with `vim`. Note that if there are no files at all in the current directory `vim` will try to open a file named `*`. If this is a problem look at the `bash` manual and search for `shopt` and `nullglob`.

If, instead, you want to open all files which first line is exactly this, you will need something else.

Comment: shopt is enabled , for instance : $ vim $(grep -d skip -l '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">' .php) doesn't work

Comment: 1) What is this `.php` at the end of your command? It was supposed to be `*`. 2) `shopt`is not enabled or disabled. It is a `bash` built-in command used to enable/disable `bash` options, one of which is `nullglob`.

Comment: 1) ```*``` is supposed to be all files , right ? so i used ```*.php``` for selecting all php files. I have lot of files. 2) i mean i used ```shopt -s globstar```. 3) i'm using git bash

Comment: OK. 4 questions: What is _a lot_? And what do you mean with _doesn't work_? Do you see an error message? What happens if you just type the `grep -d skip -l '...' *.php` part?

Comment: ok , i say lot of files because i have files in subdirectories too. files i want to access. When i type ```grep -d skip -l '...' *.php``` i see a list of all php files in the same directory.  And, when i type ```grep -d skip -l '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">' *.php``` i see all php files containing the code ```<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">' ``` , but only files in the same directory.

Comment: So, please edit your question and add all missing information (php files, in subdirectories, etc.) We cannot guess this kind of things. Help us helping you.